# python script not working when written as function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I have a python script which is to find the difference between two files which works fine but when i try to write it as a function, it is not working.

```
    def diff_tool ():

    with open('C:\\Users\\rites\\Downloads\\2018temp_new.json', encoding="utf-8") as f1:
        f1_text = f1.read().splitlines()
    with open('C:\\Users\\rites\\Downloads\\2019tempnew.json', encoding="utf-8") as f2:
        f2_text = f2.read().splitlines()

   # Find and print the diff:
    diffile= []
    diff = difflib.Differ()
    for line in diff.compare(f1_text, f2_text):
        #json.dump(line,f, indent=2)
        if line.startswith(("-", "+", "?")):
            diffile.append(line)
            #print (line, file=f)]updated=[]
            #lines = diff.splitlines()
            updated, deleted, inserted = [],[],[]
            lines = [line for line in diffile if line.find('"header"') == -1]
            for i in range(len(lines)):
                try:
                    if lines[i+1].startswith('?'):
                        if lines[i].startswith('-'):
                            updated.append(lines[i])
                            updated.append (lines[i+1])
                    else:
                        if lines[i].startswith('+'):
                            deleted.append(lines[i])
                        elif lines[i].startswith('-'):
                            inserted.append(lines[i])
                except IndexError:
                    continue
            lists = ["updated", "deleted", "inserted"]
            data = {listname: globals()[listname] for listname in lists}
            with open ('diff_result.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as outfile:
                json.dump(data,outfile)
```

I want to write this as as function which i want to later put it up as a service. I am new to python and trying it out.

When I run it in python console I am getting below key error-

```
 data = {listname: globals()[listname] for listname in lists}
KeyError: 'updated'
```

The key "updated" is present.

Comment: how is it not working? does it produce an error? does it not do anything?

Comment: Have you tried to call the function? Add to the file this: `diff_tool(f1_text, f2_text)`

Answer (score 0):

As Yann has commented, you need to call the function with:

```py
diff_tool(f1_text, f2_text)
```

And make sure to call it after your `with` statements.

Comment: I tried to run it in python console and it is throwing key error. While when i run it as script, it is running fine.